# How to load a different keyboard layout for subtype in android?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, ime, subtype

I'm using the android sample [keyboard](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SoftKeyboard/). it includes En (US) and En (GB) `subtypes`. On selecting either of the `subtypes` it only changes the flag on the spacebar.

Say I want to change the layout based on whichever `subtype` is selected but I am unable to do so.

So far, I have created another xml file for English (GB) and I call it `qwerty_gb.xml` (for the purpose of testing, I have swapped the `Return` and `Del` keys)

Then declared private

```
LatinKeyboard mQwertyKeyboardGB;
```

and initialized it along with the default keyboards in the `onInitializeInterface` overrid method of Softkeyboard.java

like so:

```
mQwertyKeyboardGB = new LatinKeyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty_gb);
```

I don't know what am I missing here.

Comment: Have you tried changing the system locale in settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit the `SoftKeyboard.java` file with following modifications in order to have specific layout for each subtype.

1- Reference your layouts first.

```
mQwertyKeyboard = new LatinKeyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty);
mPersianKeyboard = new LatinKeyboard(this, R.xml.persian);
```

2- In the `OnCreateInputView` add the following to apply the right layout.

```
InputMethodSubtype subtype = mInputMethodManager.getCurrentInputMethodSubtype();
switch(subtype.getLocale()) {
    case "fa_IR":
        setLatinKeyboard(mPersianKeyboard);
        break;
    case "en_US":
        setLatinKeyboard(mQwertyKeyboard);
        break;
}
```

The above code applies `mPersianKeyboard` if the locale is `fa_IR`. The locale `fa_IR` is set in the `method.xml`.

```
<subtype
    android:label="@string/label_subtype_generic"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_en_us"
    android:imeSubtypeLocale="en_US"
    android:imeSubtypeMode="keyboard" />
<subtype
    android:label="@string/label_subtype_generic"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_en_gb"
    android:imeSubtypeLocale="fa_IR"
    android:imeSubtypeMode="keyboard" />
```

3- And finally modify `onCurrentInputMethodSubtypeChanged method to the following:

```
@Override
public void onCurrentInputMethodSubtypeChanged(InputMethodSubtype subtype) {
    mInputView.setSubtypeOnSpaceKey(subtype);
    switch(subtype.getLocale()) {
        case "fa_IR":
            setLatinKeyboard(mSymbolsKeyboard);
            break;
        case "en_US":
            setLatinKeyboard(mQwertyKeyboard);
            break;
    };
}
```

**Note:** The `getLocale()` method was deprecated in API level 24. Use `getLanguageTag()` instead. The better is to check the version and use the right method for the right version.